# Capture response data to iframe in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, request, response

I am using the `Hubspot meeting` scheduler iframe on my website.

I am adding it the following way to my `react-app`:

```
componentWillMount(){
  this.loadScheduler();
}

loadScheduler() {
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = "https://static.hsappstatic.net/MeetingsEmbed/ex/MeetingsEmbedCode.js"
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  script.onload = () => {this.setState({ scriptLoaded: true })}
}

render() {
  if (this.state.scriptLoaded) {
    return(<div>
             <iframe src="https://app.hubspot.com/meetings/<name>/<calendar>?embed=true" width="600" height="600"></iframe>
           </div>)
  }
}
```

Now my `iframe` works properly and allows the users to schedule a date and time on the intended calendar.

As a response to scheduling a particular date/time the iframe receives the information in response to display.

Is there a way I can capture this information and save the `date/time` in my database for persistent display?

Comment: Did you manage to get some information back from the iframe? Or did you found a work around? I'm interested since I might do exactly that in the near future